# No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-manifest, ros

I'm trying to run the android_tutorial_hokuyo for android_core for ros. When I run the code, I get this error that no resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon') in my androidmanifests.xml. I also get this error for  and    .

Comment: Have you got a drawable named icon (res/drawable directory) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the icon is not very important for running the code (I suppose you just want to see how ROS works etc), you can simply delete the corresponding line in the Manifest file, it should run without any problem.
The error comes from the fact that you indeed do not have the image in your drawable resources.

Comment: I'm now able to install the app on the tablet, but it crashes because Didn't find class "org.ros.android.android_tutorial_hokuyo.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.ros.android.android_tutorial_hokuyo-1.apk"].

Comment: I suppose you first need to build the project with `Build>Rebuild Project` (Supposing you are working on Android Studio)

Comment: Yea i'm working on android studio. Nothing happened with that.